# Vuetify component, v-date-picker not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuetify.js

so I'm fairly new to vuetify and been working on making functionalities from simple components. I have used various components and one such component is **v-date-picker**.

For some reason, the calendar does not pop up when I click on the date text field.

**The gif below shows the current behaviour:**

[image: Calendar popup not being displayed]

**Expected behaviour:**

[image]

**Below is the code:**

```html
<v-date-picker 
@input="datePickerStartDate = false" 
v-model="newUnitPage1.start_date_of_unit" 
type="date" 
:show-current="false" 
:max="newUnitPage1.end_date_of_unit">
</v-date-picker>
```

Can someone tell me what could be the possible reasons for this breakage? I have checked my code throughly for **wrong variable names**, **miss assignments** and **validations**.

> Note: I'm using vuetify version 1.4

Comment: please share your tried code

Comment: Any errors in the developer console?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim which part of the code do you want? This is the code  
`<v-date-picker
              @input="datePickerStartDate = false"
              v-model="newUnitPage1.start_date_of_unit" type="date"
              :show-current="false"
              :max="newUnitPage1.end_date_of_unit"></v-date-picker>
`

Comment: @Jerodev no errors.

Comment: please edit your question with that comment

Comment: Can you share your JS too, plz ? With your data and everything. And other thing related to this date-picker, like the `v-menu` and the `v-text-field` you're using in your UI.

Answer (score 0):

So after a through debugging, I suspected something could be wrong in the version of Vuetify I'm using.

I updated it from version 1.4.0 to 1.5.2 and it works. This bug seems to be in v1.4.0 on MacOS Mojave, since I've tried it out on Ubuntu and Windows and the bug doesn't persist.